# regular expression to allow min 3 characters include spaces only

Tags: jquery, regex, asp.net-mvc-2

I want to make validation in an input text field to allow the user to enter only characters

more that 3 char and whitespace is optional.

I wanna also prevent the user from entering more than whitespace like that "          ".

ex. text to pass like that "John Adam".

I am using this regular expression "a-zA-Z ", but I have a problem when the user enter all
the text white spaces will pass.

thanks.

Comment: You want to validate in asp.net or jQuery?

Comment: Im not brill at regex but want to clarify a few things. Input has to be more than 3 a-z chars, allowed a space but no more than one at a time and cannot begin and end with a space. would this be what your looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about: `[A-Za-z]{3}([A-Za-z]+ ?)*`
or: `([A-Za-z]+ ?)*` if you already verified >=3 chars.

Comment: Thanks, but when the input like that "asd asdasdas" it will not be valid to be valid the input must be like "asdf sdgsadgsdf". Do u have solution for that?

Comment: Do you just mean >=4 instead of >=3? There are quite some inputs that are currently allowed/forbidden, where I'm not sure if this is what you intended, e.g. (for the first expression): "asdf as" is valid, but "as asdf" is not; "asd a d f g" is currently also valid. If you want each block to be at least 4, you can use "([A-Za-z]{4,} ?)*"  (or + instead of *, if the empty is not valid), etc.

Comment: simply what I mean is to the string is valid if the input is 3 characters or more with out numbers and only one space between words

Comment: Easiest way is to check a valid length independently from the other constraints. But -- disallowing leading or trailing space -- this would do the job here: "[A-Za-z]( | ?([A-Za-z]+ ?)+)[A-Za-z]"

Answer (score 0):

`([a-zA-Z]+ ?)+`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
[A-Za-z]+ *[A-Za-z ]+
```

Matches one or more letters (to prevent leading whitespace), followed by zero or more more spaces, followed by one or more letters or spaces. You could do the trimming later, but I tend to check on the validation side. Doesn't check the full string length this way, but you can get around that.

edit: Now that i'm thinking more about it, the other answer is a little more graceful - ([A-Za-z]+ ?)*

Comment: Thanks for ur help, but I wanna also to be more than 3 chars